# News relevancy identification algorithm - [NLP]

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, text-mining

I have a large set of news crawled from web as the format `[timestamp, news heading, news content as text]` I need to filter out news that are somehow related to stock market price variation in my country. For this I have pre-labeled dataset which relevant to stock market price variation.

Is there any algorithm present for finding the relevancy of large data set, so that I can filter-out relevant news??